# jquery is not working inside laravel 7 mix

Tags: jquery, laravel, npm, webpack, laravel-mix

hi I am using laravel mix to compile all js file but the jquery is not working , even I use defer attribute, can anyone find what is the problem ? thanks

inside webpack.mix.js

```
// home page css
mix.styles([
    'public/app/css/bootstrap.min.css',
    'public/app/css/custom.css',
    'public/app/css/style.default.css',
    'public/app/css/font-awesome.all.css'
], 'public/css/base.css');


// admin css
mix.styles([
    'public/assets/css/sb-admin-2.min.css',
    'public/app/css/font-awesome.all.css'
], 'public/css/admin.base.css');

mix.autoload({
  jquery: ['$', 'window.jQuery', 'jQuery'],
});


// admin js
mix.js([
    'public/assets/js/jquery.min.js',
    'public/assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js',
    'public/assets/js/jquery.easing.min.js',
], 'public/js/admin.lib.js');
```

inside blade

```
<!--   <script src="{{asset('assets/js/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
  <script src="{{asset('assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js')}}"></script>
  <script src="{{asset('assets/js/jquery.easing.min.js')}}"></script> -->



  <script src="{{asset('js/admin.lib.js')}}" defer></script>
  <script src="{{asset('assets/js/sb-admin-2.min.js')}}"></script>
```

I tried

```
mix.autoload({
  jquery: ['$', 'window.jQuery', 'jQuery'],
});
```

not working , tried to add $=jQuery inside lib.js but fails
jquery was working

if I do not use the the compiled lib.js

what is the error I am facing is the $ not defined thanks
btw , the css compilation is working though

Comment: Do your assets even compile? You have a weird path to your assets for a laravel project.

Comment: yes because i am cming from a beginer level hah

Comment: So they do compile?

Comment: yes i complied 'public/assets/js/jquery.min.js',
    'public/assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js',
    'public/assets/js/jquery.easing.min.js', thos 3 to lib.js I can see lib.js was created

Answer (score 1):

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.$ = window.jQuery = $;
```

put those 2 command from the original jquery file at the begining solved my problem thanks

follow here
https://medium.com/@nedsoft/how-to-add-jquery-ui-plugin-to-a-laravel-app-using-laravel-mix-e85bf0244fc1